# Change form language with WtForm and Flask?

Tags: flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

Sorry for being a newbie but I am having troubles changing the language for a form. I am trying out Flask with wtform but I cant change the text for name, email, etc to my native language.

```
class ContactForm(Form):
name = StringField("Name", [validators.Required("Skriv in ditt namn")])
email = StringField("Email", [validators.Required("Skriv inepostadress"), validators.Email("Är det verkligen din epostadress?")])
subject = StringField("Subject")
message = TextAreaField("Message", [validators.Required("Skriv in ett meddelande")])
recaptcha = RecaptchaField()
submit = SubmitField("Send")
```

How do I change the language so that I can use swedish chars "ÅÄÖ"? For example I want to change the value StringField("Name") to StringField("Nåme")

Comment: Do you have an error message? I'm guessing you will need `# -*- coding: utf8 -*-` at the top of your file to allow the characters

Comment: I get UnicodeDecodeError

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

I am allready using # -*- coding: utf8 -*- in every file possible.

Comment: What version of Python are you using? Does prepending the strings with `u` make a difference? `u"Är det verkligen din epostadress?"`

Comment: Mister Doherty,
That solved the issue I had. Had no idea you could append u before a string. Thank you very much for the help, much appreciated!
And by the way I am using 2.7.2 version of Python.

Comment: I will write an answer with some more details. :)

Answer (score 1):

To use special characters in your source code it is always a good idea to have:

`# -*- coding: utf8 -*-`

At the top of the file. This will allow Python to read the file correctly.

In your case you need to append a `u` to the start of your string. This marks the string as Unicode `u"Är det verkligen din epostadress?"`

This should only be needed in Python 2. In Python 3 strings are unicode by default.